# Trying to use variable when calling array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, arraylist

So people click on different items example:
Limestone, Iron Ore, Copper Ore

They click on Limestone they should see all of my info about Limestone, but I am trying to make I durable so if you click on Iron Ore it would display that.

My site has a neat routing so the URL looks like this:
/items/ores/limestone which I use to get the info of which ore we want info about.

Words after /ores/ is basically if I were to do

?ore=limestone

I can get that info and then I need to use it to display the info needed.

Well, I am trying to make it check which one you are looking at.

So if I am checking limestone out, it would display limestone, Iron Ore it would display the info about Iron ore.

But when trying to call the info about them as I've done so far is not working.

The code would work fine with following

```
item.category.ores.list.limestone.image
```

What I want is following

```
var item = {
    category: {
        ores: {
            title: "Ores",
            list: {
                limestone: {
                    name: "Limestone",
                    image: imageDirect.ores + "limestone.png",
                    stack: 100,
                    craft: {
                    }
                },
                ironOre: {
                    name: "Iron Ore",
                    image: imageDirect.ores + "ironOre.png",
                    stack: 100,
                    craft: {
                    }
                },
                copperOre: {
                    name: "Copper Ore",
                    image: imageDirect.ores + "copperOre.png",
                    stack: 100,
                    craft: {
                    }
                },
             }
         }
    }
}

var oreVal = $("#item").data("item");

var oreImage = item.category.ores.list.oreVal.image;
```

I would like it to work sort of like above, the data item contains which ore we're looking at, and depending which I am looking at it would catch the info.

I hope it makes sense, thank you.

Comment: without seeing the actual data its hard to give suggestion

Comment: I've updated it with my array

Comment: missing `oreVal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var oreVal = $("#item").data("item");
var oreImage = item.category.ores.list[oreVal].image;
```